# delete UITableViewCell with animation (error/crash)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

I'd like to delete a `UITableViewCell` & a CoreData Object from a `UITableView` with an animation. I wrote this code for doing it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let mySelectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    //1
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")

    //3
    mySelectedCell.backgroundColor = green
    mySelectedCell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Done"
    mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark        

    let person = people[indexPath.row]
    managedContext.deleteObject(person)
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)
}
```

I don't know why but the app is crashing if I select a cell, which I want to delete.

```
2015-03-29 18:00:10.776 MyApp[3001:79507] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/UITableView.m:1582
```

Crashing line: `self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)`

Does someone knows what I've done wrong?

**Update:**

```
tableView.beginUpdates()

var numberItems:Int = people.count

self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)
numberItems -= [indexPath].count // something like [indexPath].count

tableView.endUpdates()


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = people.count
    return people.count
}
```

> New error:

```
2015-03-29 19:14:15.972 MyApp[3389:89566] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/UITableView.m:1582
```

in this line of code: `tableView.endUpdates()`

Comment: Apps don't just crash.  What is the specific error message you are getting when you crash?  Which line is it crashing on?

Comment: Are you using a fetched results controller?

Comment: Yes I'm using a fetched results controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table view displays Core Data objects using a [fetched results controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/) then the *only thing* you have
to do to delete an object is to delete the object from the managed object context:

```
let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
context.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject)
```

and of course save the context to make the change permanent.

Updating the table view is then done "automatically" by the 
fetched results controller delegate methods

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)
func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)
```

You'll find a typical implementation of these methods in the
[NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate) documentation, if you haven't
implemented them already.

Also you should not have a "copy" of the fetched objects in your
`people` array. The fetched results controller is directly used
in the table view data source methods, for example:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

If you create a fresh "Master-Detail + Core Data Application" in Xcode
then you'll get all the necessary template code that you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I also like to delete the object with an animation. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: @horst: You mean delete the table view cell with animation? As I said, that should be done automatically if the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods are implemented properly. For example, `func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject ...)` calls `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)` in the case of an `.Delete` event. Create a fresh "Master-Detail + Core Data Application" in Xcode, then you'll see how it works! – Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @horst: That probably means that managedObjectContext is nil.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Now it works perfekt. The only thing I'd like to know is how to update an CoreData Object via NSFetchedResultsController. Do you know how I can do it? `newManagedObject.setValue(date, forKey: "datum")` isn't working.

Comment: @horst: to update an existing object you have to fetch it first, then change the properties.

Comment: Can you give me a code example? I tried to do it but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put yout method `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` inside this two methods in the following way :

```
var path = [NSIndexPath]()

// This is only a example with the index [0..numberOfItemsToDelete-1]
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItemsToDelete; i++) {
    path.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0))
}

tableView.beginUpdates()    

self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(path, withRowAnimation: .Right)
self.numberOfItems -= theNumberYouDeletedAbove // something like [indexPath].count

tableView.endUpdates()
```

And of course you have to update the `numberOfRowsInSection` method because it will throw a run-time error , you can do something like this :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {       
    return numberOfItems
}
```

Where `numberOfItems` match the size of the array you use to display the items.

I hope this help you.

Comment: I updated my question again. I posted the code which you said I should use and the following error.

Comment: @horst What's `[indexPath]` ? I think is `people[indexPath.row]` instead, try delete one for one

Comment: @horst See updated answer to see how to pass the `[NSIndexPath]` array

Answer (score 0):

FIRST, remove this line which try to duplicate and involve managedContext job an cause crash.

```
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)
```

SECOND, Now you should able to delete without crash and without animation.

THIRD, Let the NSFetchedResultsController delete and trigger animation in its way with "didChange" handler.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, 
    didChange anObject: Any, 
    at indexPath: IndexPath?, 
    for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, 
    newIndexPath: IndexPath?) 
    {
       print(indexPath)
       if type == .delete{
           tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
    //0.4 sec delay before refreshing the table
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + 0.4) {
        self.refresh()
    }
}
func refresh(){
    tableView.reloadData() 
}
```

If you can not delete at SECOND step;
Check, if you've implemented:

```
NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
```

in the class definition and set the delegate in the class also e.g.

```
yourResultsController.delegate = self
```